# how to set the ticker for navigation item title using Monotouch?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, uinavigationitem

I have set the title for navigation item on top of the screen. But the title text exceeded from the screen width. So I need scrolling title on the top of the screen. How to do this with MonoTouch? Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will most likely have to set a custom view for the text in the UINavigationItem's toolbar.

I have done similar with UIBarButtonItems, basically I created a UILabel with a width and centered text and set it as the custom view for it.

Take a look at this [example](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/09/custom-uinavigationbars-techniques/), it's in Objective-C but you get the idea.